# How to pass an object from Component A to Component B?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, angular, typescript

I have two components, A and B. The component B is called in component A, like so:

```
<compB></compB>
```

In component B, I have an object of type User that will save the first and last name that are inputed, and I want to pass this object to component A, so that I can present the first and last name of the user.

I tried using EventEmitter, Input and Output but I'm not really sure I'm doing things rigth.

If someone could show me a simple way of doing this or point me out some tutorials I would apreciate it!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can look for some details here...
https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/component-communication.html

Answer (score 1):

the simplest way to do it in angular is to use the `@Output` decorator.
I have created a Plunker for you that you can check over:

{{ [Here](https://plnkr.co/edit/Rn6UuQyUyZL8BoQwH6qR?p=preview) }}

basically I am passing the object from the child component (compB) to the App component (compA) with the `EventEmitter`